# Sorting arrays by a string contained in it (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I want to learn PHP. In order to do that, I'm trying to code in it. Right now I am struggling with sorting arrays.
I'm using `scandir` to look for contents of my `log` folder. I have multiple .log files in that folder. The format of their name is *the-type-of-log*_*current-date-and-time-formatted-like* `d-m-y-H-i-s`*.log*
Here I provide the actual filenames, in order for you to understand my question:
`sent_06-04-21-20-15-41.log`
`userlogin_06-04-21-18-14-50.log`
and many more. What I need to do is not to order them alphabetically, but by the date and time in their name. Is there some workaround to do it, or do I have to be satisfied with my array being ordered alphabetically?
Sorry if there are any mistakes in the question - I am trying my best not to make mistakes, but I'm not native.. :D So please excuse me.

Comment: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.usort

Comment: Since you are learning PHP with a real world example here's some helpful starting functions: `explode` (by -), and `sort`. Those two will get you pretty far with your question

Comment: If you have control over how the files are named you could just name them `06-04-21-20-15-41_sent.log`, `06-04-21-18-14-50_userlogin.log` etc when creating them

Comment: If possible, renaming the date/time part like `ymd-His` would be easier, because the date/time parts are already in order of most significant to least significant. So sorting a string in this format is easier than creating date objects and comparing those. But either way, you'll need to create a custom sort function and compare strings/dates. https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php should help too to get the last x characters of the file name.

Comment: Thank all of you! Followed @WOUNDEDStevenJones 's hint and combined it with @brombeer 's - renamed my files to `ymd-His_logtype.log` and now it's working flawlessly.